# How to convert JS Date from UTC 'Z' to timezoned date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

Hey I am receiving dates from a database which saves these dates as UTC. When I print one of the dates with console.log it looks like this `2021-04-07T07:00:00.000Z`.

Now I want to convert it into `Europe/Berlin` time. But not as a String, I want it as Javascript Date.

**What i tried to do**

I installed `date-fns` and `date-fns-tz` and I tried to use multiple functions from these packages but nothing seems to work properly or returns the correct date but again as with 'Z' suffix.

Example where testDate is the Date mentioned before

```
// using utcToZonedTime from date-fns-tz
console.log(utcToZonedTime(testDate, 'Europe/Berlin'));
// output: 2021-04-07T07:00:00.000Z

// using getTimezoneOffset from date-fns-tz
console.log(getTimezoneOffset('Europe/Berlin', testDate) / 1000 / 60)
// output: 120

// using addMinutes from date-fns to add the Offset manually
  console.log(
        addMinutes(
          testDate,
          getTimezoneOffset('Europe/Berlin', testDate) / 1000 / 60,
        ),
      );
// output: 2021-04-07T09:00:00.000Z
```

Only the last case output the correct Date but still in wrong format. How can I get a normal date in my time zone.

Comment: What happens with simply using `new Date("2021-04-07T07:00:00.000Z")`?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I get the exact same output again with the 'Z'

Comment: With `new Date`, you have the correct date as per your timezone. To get a string without 'Z', simply use string manipulation

Comment: but the Z is indicating it is UTC or isn't it? So I have to manually remove it? Is there not a better way of doing so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to convert it into Europe/Berlin time. But not as a String, I want it as Javascript Date.

That is not possible.  The JavaScript `Date` object does not *contain* any time zone information whatsoever.  The only thing it contains is a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with milliseconds precision.  In other words, the `Date` object encapsulates the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC (not counting leap seconds).  You can see this value directly with `.getTime()`, `.valueOf()`, or by any mechanism that converts the `Date` object to a `Number`.

When one observes a `Date` object and sees a time zone or a value in a particular time zone, that behavior is occurring at runtime in the function itself.  For example, the `toString` function of the `Date` object uses the local time zone of the computer when it converts the internal UTC-based timestamp to the computer's local time before returning a string that has formatted that result.

Most functions on the `Date` object work in either UTC or in the computer's local time zone (as described).  The only ones that work with other time zones are the `toLocaleString`, `toLocaleDateString`, and `toLocaleTimeString` functions, which will accept an IANA time zone identifier in the `timeZone` option.  Like the `toString` function, they only *use* this time zone when generating a string.  They do not retain it.

In short, the `Date` object does not contain a time zone, so what you ask for is not possible.

A couple of other things:

- Don't call `console.log` directly on a `Date` object.  That behavior is undefined.  Some implementations return the value of `toString` while others return the value of `toISOString`.
- Don't ever try to add/subtract an offset on a date/time unless you really know what you are doing.  In most cases, you aren't adjusting for time zone but are actually choosing a different point in time.
- Yes, `Z` at the end of an ISO 8601 timestamp means that the date and time presented are in terms of UTC.